# Filling created feature with values

Tags: machine-learning, python, feature-engineering, preprocessing

I'm trying to improve accuracy. I created a few new features based on old features. So I need to fill new feature's empty cell with same values in order to equaling shapes.Then, I tried it with median and also with mean but nothing changed. Is there any method that I can apply these cells in order to improve accuracy?

for example, there is a feature named age
I created new 2 feature named age_1 and age_2 ,
age1 consisting of age < 55 ,
age2 consisting of age > 55

therefore there is some empty cells in the new features and I have to fill these

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right - 
you've created a new feature age<55 - which gets True/False, hence, there is no need for the second feature since it has a perfect (negative) correlation with the first one (i.e False in every record that the other new feature got True..).

2 last notes:

- Note that the second feature ain't addeing any new information to the first one.
- Note that you've missed the recodes with age==55

I would suggest:

```
df['is_old'] = df['age'].apply(lambda x: x>55)
```

Comment: for example, my old feature's shape is (180,12) if I create a new feature from old feature my new feature's shape is for instance (150,12)  that's why I need to fill this rows with some values. My question is all about how i can fill these rows with

Comment: I think that a better practice is applying a function that fills the whole feature values  - and not changing the data structure by filtering it and then merging or filling it back with values. 

Anyway, if you are creating a new feature that you dont know or cant apply it's logic to the whole population - this feature wont have signal while it is missing and it wont be a good one..